# Meaning of using commas and underscores with Python assignment operator?

Tags: python, syntax, iterable-unpacking

Reading through Peter Norvig's [Solving Every Sudoku Puzzle essay](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html), I've encountered a few Python idioms that I've never seen before.

I'm aware that a function can return a tuple/list of values, in which case you can assign multiple variables to the results, such as

```py
def f():
    return 1,2

a, b = f()
```

But what is the meaning of each of the following?

```
d2, = values[s]  ## values[s] is a string and at this point len(values[s]) is 1
```

If `len(values[s]) == 1`, then how is this statement different than `d2 = values[s]`?

Another question about using an underscore in the assignment here:

```
_,s = min((len(values[s]), s) for s in squares if len(values[s]) > 1)
```

Does the underscore have the effect of basically discarding the first value returned in the list?

Comment: `_` is **just** a variable name.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`d2, = values[s]` is just like `a,b=f()`, except for unpacking 1 element tuples.

```
>>> T=(1,)
>>> a=T
>>> a
(1,)
>>> b,=T
>>> b
1
>>>
```

`a` is tuple, `b` is an integer.

Comment: So 'b,=T' means get the first element from that tuple? Is it synonymous to 'b=T[0]'? I need more examples or less wordy explanations ^^

Comment: Yes, it's the same result

Answer (score 19):

`_` is like any other variable name but usually it means "I don't care about this variable".

The second question:  it is "value unpacking". When a function returns a tuple, you can unpack its elements.

```
>>> x=("v1", "v2")
>>> a,b = x
>>> print a,b
v1 v2
```

Answer (score 8):

The _ in the Python shell also refers to the value of the last operation. Hence

```
>>> 1
1
>>> _
1
```

The commas refer to tuple unpacking. What happens is that the return value is a tuple, and so it is unpacked into the variables separated by commas, in the order of the tuple's elements.

Comment: Yeah, but in the context given above, it is a "don't care" variable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the trailing comma in a tuple like this:

```
>>> (2,)*2
(2, 2)

>>> (2)*2
4
```