# Why are the lines given as tuples in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a understanding question about the lengend in matplotlib. Here is a code example how I plot two different plots with legend

```
plt.figure(3)
line1,=plt.plot(freq,numpy.sqrt(MX*MX+MY*MY))
line2,=plt.plot(freq,numpy.abs(STAA))
plt.xlabel('offset frequency / rad/s')
plt.ylabel('magnitude of trans. magnetization')
plt.legend([line1,line2], ['analytical solution','with approximation'])
plt.show()
```

line1,= creates a tuple with one element. My question is: what is the reason matplotlib needs a tuple here instead of a "normal" object? There must be some sort of benefit I am not aware of.

cheers,
glostas

Comment: This not  a duplicate of the linked question. I edited the question such that it is more clear what I want to know. The answers found in the link are about what the ,= means (which was indeed an unsolved question before the edit) but do answer why it has to be used here which is the more interesting question.

Comment: actually, `line1,=` returns just the `Line2D` object (not a tuple), whereas `line1 =` would return a one-element list containing the `Line2D`. When you make a list from `line1` and `line2` to give to `legend`, you want just the `Line2D`, not the list

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if I understand the way python function in this case. Why is ,= returning an object and = a list? What you said is perfectly true but why is it like this?

Comment: the answer to that is in the [_possible_ duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708292/meaning-of-using-commas-and-underscores-with-python-assignment-operator)

Comment: It is the same like a=2,       then x=a gives a list while x,=a gives 2.