# Python tuple decomposition with unused elements

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking, landscape.io

I have a for-loop with with a tuple decomposition expression. maybe it's known as tuple unpacking.

Example code:

```
for funcname,func in self.GetMethods:
  # do somthing with func
  # funcname is unused
```

My code checking tool (I'm testing [Landscape.io](https://www.landscape.io/)) complains about `funcname` as a [unused variable](https://landscape.io/github/VLSI-EDA/PoC/12/modules/py/lib/ArgParseAttributes.py#L133).

**How can I satisfy Landscape.io and maybe other checkers?**

I saw loop like this:

```
for _,func in self.Getmethods:
  # loop body
```

Is `_` a:

- useless, but short identifier or
- some kind of wildcard?

Comment: It basically means you don't care about and won't be using the variable.

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1708304/3719459), covering what `_` is. But does it satisfy Landscape.io or other checkers?

Comment: It should. Did it not work when you tried it?

Comment: yes, it should do.

Comment: The release process requires same steps until my local changes are propagated to Landscape.io and I get a final report out of it :)

Comment: It is pretty much the idiomatic way to declare and unused variable in python, if it did not work I would consider your checker to be wrong more than your logic

Comment: **Ok, I can confirm that using `_` satisfies Landscape.io.**