# What does this assignment statement mean?

Tags: python, variables

I came across this Python script:

```
fea_det = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
des_ext = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

des_list = []

for image_path in image_paths:
    im = cv2.imread(image_path)
    kpts = fea_det.detect(im)
    kpts, des = des_ext.compute(im, kpts)
    des_list.append((image_path, des))
```

My issue is not related to the meaning of the different variables and parameters, but to how we can read in particular this statement:

```
kpts, des = des_ext.compute(im, kpts)
```

What would go in `kpts` and `des`? What are their data types?

Comment: Whatever `des_ext.compute` returns. You need to read the description of the function to know what it returns.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708292/meaning-of-using-commas-and-underscores-with-python-assignment-operator

Answer (score 1):

[Comma separated identifiers on LHS of assignment statement performs iterable unpacking on result of RHS](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt). Quoting docs:

> If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object
>   must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets
>   in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to
>   the corresponding targets.

*What are their data types?*

I don't know and I don't care. 
Same as Python when it performs assignment. It may care if you ask these objects to do something later.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a mechanism called **unpacking**. This is known in other languages as **destructuring assignment**.

It goes like this: when an expression evaluates to an iterable object (such as a `list` or `tuple`), you can spread the inner values to separate variables on assignment:

```
def get_2_tuple():
    return ('foo', 'bar')

values = get_2_tuple() # no unpacking
foo, bar = values # unpacking!

foo, bar = get_2_tuple() # same-line unpacking
```

The act of unpacking may `raise` an `Exception`: the function `get_2_tuple()` **must** return an iterable with **exactly** two values inside for it to work.